# How to integrate Angular's material drag and drop with virtual scrolling?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to integrate Angular material's virtual scrolling with drag and drop, but for some reason when i'm trying to implement this it reverts the items and when i'm trying to drag and drop an element it doesn't work.

Here is a summary of the code

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport cdkDropList  itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div cdkDrag *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

As you can see, I didn't do anything special, besides that I replaced `*ngFor` with `cdkVirtualFor` because the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#creating-items-in-the-viewport) are telling me that:

> `*cdkVirtualFor` replaces `*ngFor` inside of a `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`, supporting **the exact same API** as `*ngFor`.

I've attached here a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjgp5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)! So, how to integrate drag and drop with virtual scrolling?

Comment: OK, but it's wrong to add at least a "using angular material" message at the end of the question?

Comment: Nope, that's fine. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to get drag and drop working inside of virtual scroll with Angular 8.

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="10" class="viewport">
  <mat-chip-list
    class="mat-chip-list-stacked"
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="items"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <mat-chip *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" cdkDrag>
      {{ item.name }}
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

For some reason, `moveItemInArray` did not fire off change detection in the `*cdkVirtualFor` like it did for `*ngFor`.  So, I added `this.auditItems = [...this.auditItems];` to my drop event and that seemed to fix it.

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    this.items = [...this.items];
}
```

**EDIT**

As of cdk version 14.2.0 I am unable to make a working version combining both my answer and @ronenmiller.  I have created a stackblitz to reproduce the issue.  It seems even when utilizing `getRenderedRange` the index produced from the `cdkDropListDropped` does not give the anticipated result.

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6kotzc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Do you have an example of this working @Nabel?

Answer (score 5):

So the thing is, the drop list is referencing the indexes of the rendered items. So this would only work if you add the start index of the currently rendered view to the dropped item from/to indexes, like so:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport cdkDropList #virtualScroller 
  (cdkDropListDropped)="onItemDrop($event)"  itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">  
  <div cdkDrag *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

And the typescript code would have:

```
@ViewChild('virtualScroller') virtualScroller: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
...
onItemDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<FormViewOrderingItem>) {
    const vsStartIndex = this.virtualScroller.getRenderedRange().start;
    moveItemInArray(this.formViewOrdering, event.previousIndex + vsStartIndex, event.currentIndex + vsStartIndex);
}
```

For example, the event fired on drop when you move the item at index 10 to index 12 of the list when the rendered range is 2-20 will show `{start: 8, end: 10}` so when you add the rendered start index, it fixes the problem.

Hope this helps, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sry, but i think Angular materials **cdkDrag does NOT work with virtual-scroll** at the moment, see linked material [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10122) .

Following the mentioned thread there is only one [demo](https://shlomiassaf.github.io/table-demo/table-demo#/) which seems to work, but the provided [sources](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/table-demo) are sadly only available as compiled js not ts.

In fact you have to make the decision to work with [angulars drag and drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) via [cdkDrag](https://stackblitz.com/angular/moyomqpeprev?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts) OR [angulars scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) via [virtual scroll](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bavppqnorgk?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.ts).

Comment: Thanks, but if there is a complied js, then it must be a way to write that ts (from where the js belongs)

Comment: Yeah, but maybe the author don't want to make his sources public at this time. I don't know why. If your read the github issue comments, you will note several questions for sharing the code, but no response from the author ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to do this reliably thanks to the previous answers from @Nabel and @ronenmiller. I found that if you were to scroll past the current viewport while dragging an item, it will lose the original index of that control. So I'm storing the original index in the CdkDrag item attribute ID, and querying that to get the previous index. I then found that using the viewport along with the event's previous and current indices are not reliable either, so I found a way to use some simple math to calculate how many items you've scrolled before dropping the selected item, based on the original event's scroll distance, given you know the size of each item:

**HTML:**

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [itemSize]="itemSize" class="viewport">
    <div cdkDrag *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.id]="getDragItemId(i)" (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
idKey: 'my-custom-id-key-';
itemSize: number = 10;
lastDraggedIndex: number;
items: string[] = [
    'item 0',
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3',
    'item 4',
]
...
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>): void {
        // Calculate absolute distance moved (intervals of at least 10), then reapply sign for moving forward or backwards
        const difference: number = Math.round(Math.abs(event.distance.y) / this.itemSize) * Math.sign(event.distance.y);
        const currentIndex: number = this.lastDraggedIndex + difference;
            
        if (this.lastDraggedIndex !== currentIndex) {
            const newArray = [...this.items];
            moveItemInArray(newArray, this.lastDraggedIndex, currentIndex);
            this.items= [...newArray];
        }
        this.lastDraggedIndex = null;
    }
    
    dragStarted(event: CdkDragStart): void {
        this.lastDraggedIndex = this.getDragItemIndex(event.source.element.nativeElement.id);
    }
    
    getDragItemId(index: number): string {
        return `${this.idKey}${index}`;
    }
    
    getDragItemIndex(id: string): number {
        return Number(id.substring(this.idKey.length));
    }
```

NOTE: This solution isn't 100% accurate with where you drop an item if you scroll beyond the current viewport, as there's a graphical issue I haven't been able to figure out, but this should do the majority of the trick.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for something like shown in the below image, than you need to use the code of transferring items between the lists code. Check out this link https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists

And make some quick tweaks in css as per your requirement, as I have made some change in css in the browser itself to obtain the below result show in image.

You can also make 3 columns or 4 columns. Let me know if you need me to provide you the code?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need this