# Angular Material Table - When Drag and Scroll, dragged row don't drop at the right place

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I've a problem using Angular Material Table combined with Drag and Drop CDK and scrolling

When I'm dragging the line and then scrolling, the line won't be dropped where I drop it.
We can also see that the animation does'nt follow the scroll.

I think this is due to the fact than scrolling with the wheel don't move the mouse, but the row instead.
I've tried to scroll with Javascript ScrollBy and the problem is the same.

Also, it's impossible to force the scroll by going at the bottom of the Table container .

I've replicated the problem on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pebkne

Does anyone know either how to force scrolling at the end of the container or how to make sure that scrolling through the mouse wheel is working correctly?

Comment: This should be supported in the next release: https://github.com/angular/components/pull/18082 In the meantime you might be able to do it with virtual scrolling but will be tricky to overwrite the table's scrolling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817105/how-to-integrate-angulars-material-drag-and-drop-with-virtual-scrolling

Comment: In the past, I found `angular-sortablejs` (now renamed to `ngx-sortablejs`) easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was a bug in Angular Material.

It has been corrected since then.